# How to remotely connect to Ubuntu from Ubuntu using Remmina?

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina

I'm running latest Ubuntu on my machine. I'm using Remmina RDP to remotely connect to Windows machine. But I want to migrate our current Window server to Ubuntu so I have purchased a live Ubuntu server. How do I connect remotely to that Ubuntu server from Remmina? When I enter server information it says unable to connect to server. Any help? Thanks

Comment: RDP is one way. A lighter-but-stiff-full-featured alternative is a web-based frontend like [cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/), which is in the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer to my question. If you're like me a Linux noob (been running Linux for just a few months), the best approach is probably to just install a GUI on your Ubuntu Server if everything is in a terminal. If you want to do everything from a terminal, discard this but for others who want desktop, install it via Terminal.

That is what I did

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This will install a GUI and you can install other software as needed.

For RDP from Ubuntu to Ubuntu when you have the GUI. Follow this [tutorial](http://sudohttps://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Install Xfce

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies xorg dbus-x11 x11-xserver-utils
```

Install Xrdp

```
sudo apt install xrdp
```

Configure Xrdp and then use Remmina on the machine from which you wish to connect.

Comment: >> Configure Xrdp and then use Remmina on the machine from which you wish to connect.

`install a wm, now draw the rest of the owl`